# Is it possible to set a vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd for a FileType (not just a pattern)?

Tags: neovim, autocmd, filetype, lua

Currently I'm using `pattern` in `vim.api.nvim.create_autocmd()`:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufEnter", "BufFilePost" }, {
  pattern = { "*.tf" },
  callback = SetTerraformMappings,
  group = terraformGrp,
})
```

But I would prefer to use filetype somehow instead of `pattern`. In vimscript I could

```
autocmd Filetype terraform lua SetTerraformMappings()
```

Also as a workaround I can just create `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/terraform.vim` with the mappings there:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :Shell terraform plan -out latest.tfplan<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r :Shell terraform apply latest.tfplan<cr>
```

But I wonder, is there an equivalent to `autocmd Filetype xxx yyy` in  lua `nvim_create_autocmd()`?

Note that **filetype and pattern are not exactly equivalent** because filetypes sometime inspect the contents of the file to do the filetype detection.

Comment: as a workaround i'm using `vim.cmd('autocmd ...')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible write is like this in lua, just use the FileType event.

(replace your file type, I don´t what is the correct one for terraform)

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd( "FileType", {
  pattern = "yourfiletype",
  callback = SetTerraformMappings,
  group = terraformGrp,
})
```

[You can see a demonstration by awesome TJDeVries](https://youtu.be/HR1dKKrOmDs?t=29)